# Read a text file and its store contents into different files or variables

Tags: files, ksh, read

The file to read is `file.sql` containing following text

```
create table temp 
(name varchar(20), id number)  
on commit reserve rows;

create table temp1  
(name varchar(20), id number) 
on commit reserve rows;

select name, id 
from temp where id=21;
```

I want the three queries stored in three different files as below

file1.sql

```
create table temp  
(name varchar(20), id number)  
on commit reserve rows
```

file2.sql

```
create table temp1 
(name varchar(20), id number)  
on commit reserve rows
```

file3.sql

```
select name, id 
from temp where id=21
```

using ksh scripting  while retaining whitespaces

Comment: It should be trivial to split on empty lines with `awk`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
re='create table'
csplit -s -k -f file. yourSqlFile "%^$re%" "/^$re/" '/^select name,/' '/./'
for f in file.[0][0-3]; do
   k=${f#*.0}
   mv "$f" "file$k.sql"
done
for i in {2,1,0};do
   j=$((i + 1))
   mv "file$i.sql" "file$j.sql"
done
```

Comment: can you please explain the above script

Comment: `csplit` splits files on context which is provided by arguments to csplit, in particular, "%...%", "/.../" For more info do a `man csplit`